# Solving logarithmic equation with different bases

Tags: logarithms

$\log_2\left(x-5\right)=\log_5\left(2x+7\right)$ I have to solve this but my answer vary from x = 7, x = -9, x = 5/3 and I don't know why this happens.
Here is my approach:

$\frac{\log_5\left(x-5\right)}{\log_5\left(2\right)}=\log_5\left(2x+7\right)$

$\frac{\log_5\left(x-5\right)}{\log_5\left(2x+7\right)}=\log_5\left(2\right)$

$\log_{2x+7}\left(x-5\right)=\log_5\left(2\right)$

Conditions: x > 5

So we are left with:
x - 5 = 2 => x = 7 (verifies the conditions)

2x + 7 = 5 => x = -1 (does not verify the conditions)

Therefore, x = 7.

But when you plug in x = 7 => $\log_2\left(2\right)=\log_5\left(21\right)$ which are not equal.

I guessed a solution that works which is x = 9.

trying to solve that system, i found another way to solve it

x - 5 = 2 | *(-1)

2x + 7 = 5

=>   - x + 5 = -2

```
  2x + 7 = 5
```

We add them up and we have:

x + 12 = 3 => x = -9 which does not verify the condition.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You say $x-5 =2$ verifies *one* condition and $2x + 7 = 5$ fails the condition.  Why would you assume these are the only two options?  I might be wrong, but I'm pretty sure there are more than two real numbers.

Comment: Ah... I see.  You are assuming that if $\log_a b = \log_c d$ means that either $b = d$ or $a = c$.  That's simply wrong.

Comment: @fleablood oh... i see... then what should i do?

Comment: If it is  known that $x$ is an integer just plug in the numbers $6,7,8,9,10,11,...$

Comment: @callculus so you're telling me there is no way of solving this but just guessing?

Comment: @C.Cretan Do you know that the solution is an integer?

Comment: @callculus no..

Comment: @C.Cretan Then I don´t see a smart way to solve the equation.

Answer (score 1):

$\log_2(x-5) = \log_5(2x+7)=k$

$2^k = x-5$ so $x = 2^k + 5$.  $5^k =2x - 7$ so $x = \frac {5^k -7}2$

Or $2*2^k +10 = 5^k - 7$

$2^{k+1} = 5^k-17$

[cute that $2^{k+1} -8 = 5^k -25$... but, I'll assume I wasn't clever enough to see that.]

At this point we can really only guess but clearly if we increase $k$ by small incrementss the RHS will increase more than the LHS, so there is only one solution and we can hone in on values.  If the RHS is larger than the LHS we take smaller values of $k$ and vice versa.

$2^{1+1} > 5^1 - 17$ so $k > 1$

And $2^{3 + 1} < 5^3 - 17$ so $k < 3$

It's simple enough to discover $k = 2$ is a solution..

(Even simpler if we noticed $2^{k+1} - 8 = 5^k - 25$ so $2^3 - 8 = 5^2 - 25 = 0$)

So $x = 2^2 + 5 = \frac{5^2 - 7}2 = 9$.